# Publishing a "permanent" cppcheck report

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cppcheck

By default, Jenkins associates a cppcheck report with a particular build (which makes sense). The problem is, if the number of builds to save is limited, then the link to the report for that build will become invalid when the build gets deleted. Is there anyway to have a "latest cppcheck report" link where the report for the last build will be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the build number in the URL with 'lastStableBuild' as, for example: 
 
https://jenkins.site.com/view/job/Project_X/lastStableBuild/cppcheckResult/